# IE11 throws error in IEFRAME

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript

When I try to see "properties" of [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)'s logo, IE11 shows script error in file res://ieframe.dll/anchbrws.js

Looking at the file, I see

```
 function BodyLoad() {
     var arrAll = document.all;
     for (i=0; i < arrAll.length; i++) {
        var elm = arrAll[i];
        if (elm.id.substring(0,1) == "_") {
            if (elm.innerText== "undefined" || elm.innerText == "") {
                elm.innerText = L_NotAvailable_Text;
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

from what I see, trying to read `document.all` is a stupid idea to do in IE11, which puts me to concern - is this a bug in IE's internal script or I have old version of some file(s) or my PC was compromised ?

p.s: this error does not happen on other pages, nor on other elements of JSFiddle site.

Comment: I'm running Windows 8.1 with the latest IE11 here, and it does it for me as well.  Looks to be a bug of some kind.  Strange for sure.

Answer (score -3):

Go to Control Panel > Network & Internet > Internet Options > Advanced

Click **Return to default** (the button at bottom), mark *Erase personal settings* and confirm.

After all is done, restart windows.